How to generically restrict the domain of an axiom?
I need to figure out an elegant and mathematically precise way to restrict the domain of a collection of axioms.
Let $N$ and $A$ be arbitrary finite sets, let $\mathcal{P}(A)=\bigl\{P\mid P=(P_i)_{i\in N}:P_i\text{ is a linear order over }A\bigr\}$ be the set of all linear order profiles on $A$, let $F=\{f\mid f:\mathcal{P}(A)\to A\}$ be the set of all functions from $\mathcal{P}(A)$ to $A$, and let $\{X_1,\dots,X_7\}$ be a collection of seven axioms (or properties) for functions $f\in F$. Further, let $\hat{\mathcal{P}}(A)\subsetneq\mathcal{P}(A)$, and let $\hat{F}=\{\hat{f}\mid\hat{f}:\hat{\mathcal{P}}(A)\to A\}$ be the set of all restricted functions.
I need to define a new collection of axioms $\{\hat{X}_1,\dots,\hat{X}_7\}$ which is analogous to $\{X_1,\dots,X_7\}$, but for restricted functions $\hat{f}\in\hat{F}$ rather than functions $f\in F$. The idea is that the new axioms are the identical to the original ones, but are defined only on functions $\hat{f}\in\hat{F}$ and their restricted domain $\hat{\mathcal{P}}(A)$. I really do not know how to achieve this goal.
One possibility is to re-write each axiom; but given that I have a total of seven axioms, re-writing them all one by one seems unnecessarily repetitive.
I am thus trying to figure out an elegant way to generically restrict a collection of axioms.
EXAMPLE: I realise that my question is rather abstract, since I am not saying which axioms I need to restrict. So, I now provide one of said axioms as an example. The following axiom is a common axiom in social choice and mechanism design, called monotonicity.
Given any linear order profile $P\in\mathcal{P}(A)$, any $i\in N$ and any $x\in A$, let $L_i(x,P)=\{y\in A\mid xP_iy\}$, and let $\mathcal{P}(A|P,x)=\{P'\in\mathcal{P}(A)\mid(\forall i\in N)[L_i(x,P)\subseteq L_i(x,P')]\}$.
A function $f\in F$ is monotonic if and only if
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
(\forall P\in\mathcal{P}(A))(\forall P'\in\mathcal{P}(A|P,f(P)))(f(P)=f(P'))
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
Then, I would like to define motonicity for restricted functions $\hat{f}\in\hat{F}$ as follows.
A restricted function $\hat{f}\in\hat{F}$ is monotonic if and only if
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
(\forall P\in\hat{\mathcal{P}}(A))(\forall P'\in\hat{\mathcal{P}}(A|P,\hat{f}(P)))(\hat{f}(P)=\hat{f}(P'))
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
While I could re-write all my axioms one by one as indicated above, I would rather have a systematic way of defining them all at once.

Than you very much for your comment. Unfortunately, I can’t quite see what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

You could have a parametric set of axioms, where specializations of the parameters give concrete sets of axioms.  For instance.
Let $N$ and $A$ be arbitrary finite sets, $P$ be a set of sequences of elements of $A$, $F$ be the set of functions $P \rightarrow A$.  The collection $\mathrm{Ax}(N,A,P,F)$ of axioms is:

Axiom $x_1(N,A,P,F)$: blah blah $f \in F$, then blah blah
...

Let $P = \mathcal{P}(A)$ be the set of linear order profiles on $A$.  We study the specilizations:

$\mathrm{Ax}_1 = \mathrm{Ax}(N,A,P,F)$ and
$\mathrm{Ax}_2 = \mathrm{Ax}(N,A,\hat{P},\hat{F})$, where $\hat{P} \subsetneq P$ (and $\hat{F}$ is necessarily $\left. F \right|_{\hat{P}}$, the restriction of $F$ to $\hat{P}$).


I have accepted your answer because I think it works. Nonetheless, after reading other papers in my field which deal with similar problems, I ended up doing something different: namely, I defined my functions with variable domains, and stated my axioms on the domain of the function, whatever that may be.
